# AngularJS routes and search query

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-parameters, query-string

I'm building a small search engine using Angular and UI Router. I'm trying to figure the best way to transition from the home page (search submission) to the results page.

I have this for my home page route(state in UI Router)

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/',
```

And then I this for my search results page

```
.state('search', {
        url: '/search?q',
```

I want to have the user's search term that is submitted on the home page to be in the url of the search results page. How can I best do that with UI Router? It seems that abstract state might be necessary here to pre-load the home page(template, controller and url) and then have another state such as

```
.state('home', {
        url: '?q',
```

Where q is used for query parameter... however it doesn't quite seem to work. Is my thinking here way off or do I have an error in my code somewhere that I don't see?

Comment: `$state.go('search', { q: theValueBeingSubmitted })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass query params to UI Router via the `$state.go` API like so:

#### via controller

```
var params = { q: <user-input> }
$state.go( 'search', q )
```

#### via directive

```
<a ui-sref="search({ q:<user-input> })">Search</a>
```

$state API docs - [link](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state)